# Trying to route audio from Musescore to Ableton Live 10 via JACK audio connection?

Tags: audio, midi, vst, jack, ableton-live

My goal is to be able to write sheet music in Musescore and then have the audio output of the playback routed to Ableton Live.

[image: JACK and Ableton settings]

I've tried using loopMIDI audio and LoopBe1 as virtual midi cables.

I have the Jack audio driver set in Ableton's audio preferences under ASIO drivers. As seen in the photo, it seems that Ableton is recognizing the virtual midi cables as an input. I have Musescore's Jack audio settings enabled. I have a midi instrument set up in Ableton. However, when I play back audio in Musescore Ableton doesn't seem to be recognizing any input.

I was trying to follow along with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Se6SuINxnaI) tutorial. However, they seemed to omit certain details. For example, as seen in my image I was only able to route general sound/midi devices together not specific [left1,right1] to another [in1,in2]

Comment: I don't know Musescore, but it sounds like your mixing up audio and midi. Midi is not audio - only a digital representation of what notes are played, but not how they should sound. Audio is a stream of samples... Does Musescore output Midi?

Comment: What exactly do you mean output midi? Musescore certainly uses MIDI and it can export MIDI files? Additionally JACK support is a feature of Musescore. I'm not sure why this would be included if it couldn't output MIDI?

Comment: Can you show us your input setting on the Ableton track you have the MIDI routing to? A couple of things I can think of: recording needs to be armed and you need to have the channel set to the correct MIDI channel.